# Cannot install any appxpackage on Windows Server 2022 Core because windows.capability extension is not registered

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-core, windows-server-2022, appx

Installing anything via `Add-AppxPackage` cmdlet results in error:

```perl
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be
registered.
error 0x80040154: Cannot register the request because the following error was
encountered while initializing the windows.capability extension: Class not registered
.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId]
66806e04-39e0-0000-bb37-17e40d75d901 in the Event Log or use the command line
Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 66806e04-39e0-0000-bb37-17e40d75d901
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage .\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Admin\...00.Desktop.appx:String) [Ad
   d-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Comm
   ands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

I think this message says that the appx package has a `<windows.capability>` section in manifest xml, but the related handler is not registered.

What should I do? What can I do?

Comment: Hi, is it a package that need the desktop experience to run ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 that's also one of my questions. But I don't this VC library, as the dependency for many other packages need the desktop experience. By the way, WSL Ubuntu 22.04 depends on this VC library, but 20.04 does not. 20.04 also get this error (windows.capability not registered)

Comment: My ultimate goal is to install wsl on this server core. Please tell me if you have any idea